# Error in installing openfire in windows8

Tags: java, openfire

I am trying to install openfire in windows8 and its showing the following error.Can Any body please tell me how to solve this issue?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\lib\commons-el.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:90)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\lib\hsqldb.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:90)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\lib\jasper-compiler.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:90)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\lib\jasper-runtime.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:90)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\lib\jtds.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:90)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\lib\mysql.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:90)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\lib\openfire.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:90)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\lib\postgres.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:90)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\lib\servlet.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:90)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\lib\slf4j-log4j12.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:90)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Openfire\bin\..\plugins\admin\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\admin-jsp.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:101)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Openfire\bin\..\plugins\admin\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-fileupload.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:101)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Openfire\bin\..\plugins\admin\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-io.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:101)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Openfire\bin\..\plugins\admin\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\dwr.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.unpackArchives(ServerStarter.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:101)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:111)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

Note: I am downloading from this [site](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/) and choosed windows platfporm and after that I downloaded  [openfire_3_9_1.exe Includes Java JRE (recommended)](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/download-landing.jsp?file=openfire/openfire_3_9_1.exe)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Openfire forums](http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/237937), the accepted answer is:

> close it all down, then right-click --> run as administrator

Additionally, it is best practice to not use the exe but instead install it as a service as SnakeDoc recommended.  You can do that by running `openfire-service /install` from the commandline in Openfire's `bin` directory.  You can also [view Openfire's documentation](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/install-guide.html) on how to install the service

Comment: Only if running the exe launcher. this is designed really only for testing purposes. For a production setup, it's much better to run it as a windows service (limits permission scope, starts/stops automatically, etc).

Comment: Yes, that is true. I was simply referencing the accepted answer on that thread, as it looks like the message is identical (probably the same user).  Additionally, the user asked on that forum to answer the SO question as well.

Comment: you're correct on all 3 accounts ;-P   -- simply making sure future readers of this SO thread know the context in which running as administrator was suggested :)

Comment: Yep. I edited my answer to include your suggestion :)

Comment: @MikeKoch I am that person who have posted in openfire forum.what is your username in openfire forum

Comment: @SnakeDoc are you also snakedoc from openfire forum?

Comment: @MikeKoch ok,well do you have any exp in using openfire?Actually I have just started today

Comment: @JqueryLearner not much.  I have a server that *was* running it for a while, but I shut down Openfire on it since I haven't used it in forever.  If you need support, best place is to return to the Openfire forums.

Comment: @JqueryLearner yes :)

Comment: @MikeKoch I was told to go throgh this http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html in my college but I dont know what is this for

Comment: @SnakeDoc I have configuring openfire.xml by looking this http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html. so how would I know that the configuration is correct? Can I see any output anywhere?

Comment: let's move this back to the forums, as stackoverflow doesn't like conversations in comments ;-P   -- i asked you some more questions on your post in teh forums.

Comment: @SnakeDoc can you please come to my room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44929/java-and-jquery-beginners

Comment: @JqueryLearner sorry, i'm at the office and didn't notice your invite. if you post back in the igniterealtime.org forums, somebody will be able to help :)

Comment: @JqueryLearner if this answer is the answer you are looking for, please feel free to mark it as accepted, so other users know that this answer is the one to read. Plus the extra rep is a nice feature too :)

Comment: @MikeKoch I have already got answers in openfire forum and my problem was solved before this answer.Also if you see that forum many are saying that by opening openfire.exe by giving administrator rights is not the right way.Still I have accepted your answer to give you 15 reps.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Actually I am not understanding why the openfire.xml is for?what is its use and can we see users info(users email,name,etc) are already present in mysql database